# Django Serializer returns curried method instead of value for get_FOO_display

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I use DRF's Model Serializer class to (de)serialize my models, and until staring a new project *today* I was always able to return a Choice Field's [display name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) like so:

```
class StatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.ChoiceField(source='get_status_display',
                                     choices=Status.STATUS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields = ('id', 'status')
```

My simple example `Status` model looks like

```
class Status(models.Model):
    STATUS_PROCESSING = 0
    STATUS_COMPLETE = 1
    STATUS_ERROR = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_PROCESSING, 'Processing...'),
        (STATUS_COMPLETE, 'Processing Complete'),
        (STATUS_ERROR, 'Processing Error'))

    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                 default=STATUS_PROCESSING)
```

in the Django shell I do the following:

```
>>> s = Status.objects.create(status=0)
>>> s.get_status_display() # this works
'Processing...'
>>> StatusSerializer(s).data # returns the method itself
{'status': <bound method curry.<locals>._curried of <Status: Status object>>, 'id': 1}
```

I can see why this would be happening (the serializer is not invoking the `source` attribute but instead just referencing it), but this used to work in the past! I am running a virtual env with Python 3.5.2 on Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.1

```
Django==1.10.2
djangorestframework==3.5.1
```

**UPDATE**
I downgraded this example project to the following:

```
Django==1.10
djangorestframework==3.4.4
```

And the display name for `Status` is as expected. There is an existing bug report on DRF here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4602

Comment: It's a regression in DRF, fixed by 3.5.2 today: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4602

Comment: awesome, thank you!